# what does "MemoryError: None" mean in Python? And why display the refine_conflict(model) make the process different?

Tags: python, callback, cplex

My python project calls docplex and uses lazy constraints, but running it directly displays "Integer infeasible" after a few seconds. But when I use the following code to show constraint conflict, it will run for about 90mins and report "MemoryError: None", I want to know what does "None" stand for, and whether there is not enough memory or not. Secondly, why does this code that shows constraint conflicts make the model different and not say "Integer infeasible" so quickly? Thank you.

```
refiner = ConflictRefiner()
res = refiner.refine_conflict(model)
res.display()
```

```
\--\> lazy constraint callback called: #16
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\Users\\zane\\test\\cplex_for_ARP.py", line 322, in solve_arc_routing
    res = refiner.refine_conflict(model)
  File "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\docplex\\mp\\conflict_refiner.py", line 428, in refine_conflict
    results = self.\_refine_conflict_local(mdl, context, preferences, groups)
  File "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\docplex\\mp\\conflict_refiner.py", line 471, in \_refine_conflict_local
    return self_engine.refine_conflict(mdl, preferences, groups, parameters)
  File "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\docplex\\mp\\cplex_engine.py", line 2296, in refine_conflict
    cpx.conflict.refine(\*cplex_def_grs)
  File "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\cplex_internal_subinterfaces.py", line 8761, in refine
    grppref, grpbeg, grpind, grptype)
  File "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\cplex_internal_procedural.py", line 2298, in refineconflictext
    check_status(env, status)
  File "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\cplex_internal_procedural.py", line 238, in __call__
    \_handle_cb_error(env, callback_exception)
  File "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages\\cplex_internal_procedural.py", line 210, in \_handle_cb_error
    raise cberror

MemoryError: None
```

Comment: The conflict refiner isn't trying to find a solution for your problem. Instead it is trying to find a small (irreducible) subset of your problem that is infeasible as this often gives more useful information about why your problem is infeasible. That means that it is often much slower running the conflict refiner than just solving your problem or proving it to be infeasible.

Comment: Yes, adding it does make it longer. Thanks.
But I'd also like to know what "Memoryerror: None" means, does anyone know?